# add libpq-fe.h to qt existing project

Tags: c, qt, gcc, linker, libpq

I have a C code that uses libpq-fe.h for connecting into a postgresql database. Locally it runs well and everything but now we are trying to use it in a QT existing project.
Why not using the qpsql driver instead? Well, the program itself is in plain c++ but we just use QT as an extra help for programmiing so the question is...
How can I tell QT to link the code with the header against the libpq-fe.h?
We tried adding the path like
`LIBS += -I/usr/include/postgresql`
and 
`LIBS += -lpq` 
but without results...
We also tried adding the CPPFLAGS to the makefile as the documentations says but when recompiling, the program recreates the makefile so it's no use
Suggestions?

Comment: You don't need to add directories under `/usr/include` at pro file. What is your problem? Did it fail to build or did not find any header? Please be specific. Post some code.

Comment: My code has the header `#include<libpq-fe.h>` and I'm using Qt but when I try to build it fails reporting this problem : `libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory` and that's because, when you build code with libpq library, you need tu compile against it using `I/usr/include/postgresql -L/usr/lib -lpq` wherever your libpq header may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
INCLUDEPATH += -I"/usr/include/postgres"
LIBS += -L"[directory to postgres library files]" -lpq
```